# Read .csv file (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: spring-boot, csv, filereader

I have create a REST API POST in order to read a file csv and than update my postgres table in this way:

```
@Override
public void insertDataFromCSV(CsvDataInputBean csvDataInputBean)
        throws IllegalStateException, FileNotFoundException {

    String path = csvDataInputBean.getPath();
    log.info("INPUT PATH ", csvDataInputBean.getPath().toString());

    List<CsvPojo> csvFile = new CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvPojo>(new FileReader(path)).withType(CsvPojo.class).build()
            .parse();

    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

    for (CsvPojo csv : csvFile) {
        log.info("CSV User Name: ", csv.getName());
        log.info("CSV User Surname: ", csv.getSurname());
        log.info("CSV User Gender: ", csv.getGender());
        log.info("CSV User Age: ", csv.getAge());
        log.info("CSV User CF: ", csv.getCf());
        log.info("CSV User Mail: ", csv.getMail());
        log.info("CSV User Address: ", csv.getAddress());

        userEntity.setId(csv.getId());
        userEntity.setName(csv.getName());
        userEntity.setSurname(csv.getSurname());
        userEntity.setGender(csv.getGender());
        userEntity.setAge(csv.getAge());
        userEntity.setCf(csv.getCf());
        userEntity.setMail(csv.getMail());
        userEntity.setAddress(csv.getAddress());
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        userRepository.flush();
        log.info("Saved the Record: ", csv.getId());
    }

}
```

But when I try to test on Postman I get this error:

```
2023-05-02 17:13:21.251 ERROR 13816 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.controller.UserController          : EXIT 'Controller'='UserController', Method='insertDataFromCSV(csvDataInputBean)', Error='C:\Users\PastoreGu\Download\csv\User.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)'
2023-05-02 17:13:21.256 ERROR 13816 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.controller.UserController          : The stack trace is :

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PastoreGu\Download\csv\User.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

The file is correct present in the folder specified in the path.

Could you please help me??

Comment: I think error msg is correct! Please check your folder or move csv file to another folder!